# WiFi isn't working in new installation of Ubuntu

Tags: wireless, 17.04

It's Linux and everything should be setup manually, but I'm new to this and need help in setting up my WiFi.

here's what I did. I installed ubuntu, tried to connect the WiFi while installation it didn't got connected, I thought well it'll connect once it got installed but it still isn't connected. I think it should be pretty easy to solve, something I forgot to tick or something

a thing to notice is that it says it's connecting for few seconds and doesn't get connected after that

Comment: what's your output of `cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

Comment: @user535733 what? **No**

Comment: @user535733 works fine on Windows, hardware is working, let me try the answer

Comment: For those who are still looking for some solution, I searched for several days, the solution is therefore to update the kernel to 5.10 or 5.12 example, I had 5.8 on 20.04.2 LTS with a dual boot, neither wireless or bluetooth worked, I upgraded the kernel to 5.12 via https://askubuntu.com/a/1291835/855698 and it works now.

I hope it will help those who will have this trouble.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you need to do is Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and run:

```
gksu gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

At the bottom of this file, copy and paste the following:

```
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

final result will look like this

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

Then just save and close the file and run:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

And wifi should work again!