# Is there a kernel 5.8 ppa for ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: apt, kernel, updates, ppa

I have a laptop with an AMD Ryzen 7 and ubuntu 20.04 installed. Various things wouldn't work initially: The screen wouldn't turn back on when resuming from sleep, the screen brightness fn-keys wouldn't work properly, I wasn't able to switch to wayland (I swear, there was no gear icon in the login screen). Possibly more, but that is what bothered me.

I was able to resolve all these issues by installing the 5.8 kernel line. Because I did this by manually downloading and installing .deb packages, I now have a few problems:

- apt thinks it's appropriate to install the 5.4 kernel again once that package (linux-headers-...) receives updates.
- To receive 5.8 kernel updates, I have to manually download and install the latest .deb packages.

All the sites that pop up when searching for "ubuntu 20.04 kernel 5.8 {ppa,updates}" only present manual solutions, be it via wget-ing .deb's, using a script, or using some other GUI application.

What I'm used to from ubuntu, would be to add a ppa to my `/etc/apt/sources.list` and after doing `$ apt install linux-headers-5.8.x-x` once, I would continue to receive updates by doing `$ apt update && apt upgrade`.

Is there such a ppa?

Comment: @guiverc Enabling proposed is not a good idea and may have a lot of side effects ;-)

Comment: Yes thanks @Pilot6, it would cause a lot more updated packages to be installed, had someone 'leapt' on what I just said without thinking about it; my pointing to your answer was I felt cover enough, but maybe not.  My primary point was the upgrade is coming with 20.04.2 (why I could see it with `apt-cache search`..)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can install the 5.8 kernel to Ubuntu 20.04 now by running

```
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-20.04-edge
```

The kernel will get updates.

But if you wait some time (it is a matter of days) `linux-generic-hwe-20.04` (without `edge`) will also pull the 5.8 kernel.

**Update:** Now we have `linux-generic-hwe-20.04` pointing to the `5.8` kernel. If you've installed the `edge`, it is better to remove it by

```
sudo apt remove linux-{image,headers}-generic-hwe-20.04-edge
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-20.04
```

Comment: out of curiosity: where did you find the info, that `linux-generic-hwe-20.04` will pull 5.8 in the near future? Or rather, where can I check if it's ready yet?

Comment: You can check it here https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=linux-generic-hwe-20.04 I am also waiting for 5.8 to be official hwe for 20.04.

Comment: Still not here...

Comment: Finally it's there.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use different kernels, you can *also* use the [Ubuntu Mainline Kernel Installer](https://github.com/bkw777/mainline). This will let you pick from a variety of kernels, usually long before they make it to Ubuntu's defaults. So, we can add this to the list of choices you can make.

It's pretty straightforward.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cappelikan/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mainline
```

From there, you just open the application and pick the kernel you'd like to use, install it, and then reboot to use the new kernel. It is fairly intuitive and looks a bit like this:

[image: Ubuntu Mainline Kernel Installer]

The app can be rather annoying with multiple notifications. You can change the frequency of checks in the application's settings. You can also click on 'changes' and see what changes (the changelog) have been made to the kernels.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for share!